# angularjs list of all the unit testing methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

does anyone know where I can find a list of all the unit testing methods for AngularJs.
I am aware of ones such as .toEqual(), toHaveBeenCalled(). but a list would be helpful. I need one for example that says .toBeGreaterThan() or isGreaterThan().
I have looked here `https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing` but it only gives ones I am already aware of.
any ideas/suggestions

Comment: Are you using jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution. I meant Jasmine matchers rather than Angular ones. but here is a link if anyone else ever needs one `http://blog.bandzarewicz.com/blog/2012/03/08/jasmine-cheat-sheet/`